# JQuery Ajax Undefined when there's an actual response

Tags: jquery

I am having a really strange problem.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: $('#ContactForm').serialize(),
    success: function (response) {

        $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);

        $('.form_result').html(response.responseText); //This displays 'yes'

        var res = response.responseText;

        alert(res); //This returns 'undefined'

        if (res = 'yes') {
            alert('The Login is RIGHT');
        }; //This does not see 'yes' as it should 

    }
});

return false;
```

In resume:

The php page is returning 'yes';

```
$('.form_result').html(response.responseText); //is returning 'yes'

alert(res); //is returning 'undefined'

and if(res = 'yes') { //... Returns false when it should return true...
```

Any ideas? It's driving me crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using `jQuery 1.9.1v`, then this is a bug which has been raised with jQuery official site already.

check Here for more info

https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax/issues/95

Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `res` to `'yes'` not checking if `res == 'yes'`

```
        if (res == 'yes') {
            alert('The Login is RIGHT');
        }; //This does not see 'yes' as it should
```

Comment: what about this? alert(res); //This returns 'undefined' ??

Comment: $('.form_result').html(response.responseText); returns - yes    ... BUT alert(response.responseText) or alert(res) ... both return Undefined

Comment: What does `console.log(response.responseText)` display?

Comment: I cannot tell whether `responseText` is being set by your php since it is not included in your question

Comment: The Response on Console in Firebug returns 'yes'